# Go Golang - embedding types and "len/range"

Tags: go

```
package m
type M map[int]int
// have methods on M
// can use len and range on M

package n
// need methods of M
type N struct { M }
// methods available
// BUT cannot use len or range on N
// if " type N M " - I lose the methods on M
```

Need the methods of M and len/range functionality in a different package. How can this be done ?

Comment: `len(n.M)` and `... := range n.M`. No other way without redefining the methods on `N` or converting it to `M` before using the methods.

Comment: Actually aliases might work https://play.golang.org/p/ErTfzQ_Mbvj , although i'm not sure they were meant to be used for that...

Comment: aliases work, for len/range BUT then I lost the methods :)

Comment: Actually with [aliases](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) you don't lose the methods and you also can use len/range on the alias, but you cannot add new methods to it. Its intended for refactoring I believe. Note that aliases have `=` between the identifiers. `type N = M` is an alias, `type N M` is not an alias, although I'm not sure what you would call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring packages (they don't matter in this scenario), you need to specify a valid type for the builtins `len` and `range`:

```
type M map[int]int

func (m *M) SayHi() {
    fmt.Println("Hi!")
}

type N struct{ M }

func main() {
    var foo N
    fmt.Println(len(foo.M))
    for k, v := range foo.M {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %d\n", k, v)
    }
    foo.SayHi()
}
```

`foo.SayHi()` works because `SayHi` is promoted to `struct N`.

However, `len` and `range` are not methods on `M`, they are builtins that expect specific types. Embedding does not change the type, it promotes methods from the embedded field to the container struct.

You can read more about the details in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Maybe because I'm new to Go, but that does not seem intuitive.